# how to use mongoose typings with angular 2 webpack starter

Tags: angular, typescript, mongoose, webpack, typing

I'm fairly new so this should be simple.

I'm using [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

according to [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/unstable/docs/browser.html), I can get a global variable for mongoose if I include their js file

if I do `declare var mongoose : any;` things work but I want typings for mongoose. I can't seem to get how to add those.

Once I do `npm install @types/mongoose -S` I can see the file `node_mudles/mongoose/index.d.ts` how do I tell typescripte that the variable `mongoose` is of a type from that file?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you install `mongoose` and `@types/mongoose`, you have to just import it.

Check [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/mongoose)

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

Also, make sure you have the below set in your `tsconfig.json` inside `compilerOptions`.

```
 "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
```